# img exchange iteration timeout with js

Tags: javascript, html

I found this javascript code which takes my images from #animation and runs them in a loop one by one:

```
onload = function startAnimation() { 

var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
var frameCount = frames.length;
var i = 0;


onload = setInterval(function () { 

    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";

    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";

    }
}, 300);
}
```

I have 2 questions about it:

1. how do I get it to make a pause of 2 seconds when it gets to the last image.
2. I will really appriciate if anyone can explain this bit of code:

frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";

frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";

I never saw something like that. it looks like for loop but different.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Try this

> ```
> var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
>
> var frameCount = frames.length;
> var i = 0;
> var x1 = 2000;
>
> function calllink() {
>
>   frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
>
>   frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
>
>   if ((i % frameCount) == (frameCount - 1)) {
>     setTimeout(calllink, x1);
>   } else {
>     setTimeout(calllink, 300);
>   }
> };
> setTimeout(calllink, 300);
> ```

Here is an example where I implemented the above logic [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjftk0vs/)

---

**2.** `i % (modulus) frameCount` is for keeping the count within 0 to max frame count for infinite time.

Example:

```
Let frameCount = 10 and i = 0

i % frameCount = 0 % 10 = 0

++i % frameCount = 1 % 10 = 1

...
...
```

When i `== frameCount` i.e. `i == 10`, there won't be any 10th frame (frames are from 0 to 9)

So,

```
10 % 10 = 0
11 % 10 = 1

...
...
And so on..
```

And every time the function is called, it sets the next frame to be visible and hides the previous frame.

Comment: Oww I see. Thanks! waiting for your answer about the first question!

Comment: if there is a different way of writing this I will be glad to see also.

Comment: would you be kind to find an answer to my first question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a good answer here by @Roberto but somehow it was deleted.
I would be happy if anyone can post again an example on how to make the code pause after each loop.